# Compute softmax activation function using python

Tags: python, numpy, softmax

I was trying to write a method to compute the SoftMax activation function that takes either a matrix or an array as input and apply the softmax function to each rows.

Here is what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
def softmaxSingle(x):
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
    return e_x / e_x.sum()    

def softmax( x):
    if np.shape(x)[0]>1:
        result=[[]]*np.shape(x)[0]
        for i in range(len(result)):
            result[i]=list(softmaxSingle(x[i]))
        return list(result)
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
    return e_x / e_x.sum()
```

When I tried `SoftMax(x)` where `x` is a matrix, It runs(although I don't know if it produces correct answer). When `x` is just a list, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make a `list` to `np.array` conversion:

```
import numpy as np

def softmax(x):
    """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
    if isinstance(x, list):
        x = np.array(x)
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
    return e_x / e_x.sum()
```

Comment: But 'x-np.max(x)' method doesn't substract each row by the max of each row, it substract each row by the max of all entries, Is that ok? Try this for example:   a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
print(a-np.max(a))   and the output of that is :  [[-5 -4 -3]
 [-2 -1  0]]

Comment: @user42493 Can you give me sample input? And yes, it needs to subtract every element by the max of that matrix, don't you think? If row-wise is a requirement then you can still work it that way

Comment: Ok, what about e_x.sum() ? that gives the sum of all entries in the matrix, but we need to divide each row of e_x by the sum of each row e_x?

Comment: From the docs: *Axis or axes along which a sum is performed. The default, axis=None, will sum all of the elements of the input array. If axis is negative it counts from the last to the first axis.*